# Function SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Como faço para realizar a função que retorne número de créditos de um determinado curso passando por parramento o código? Conforme o exemplo no final.

#### TB_DISCIPLINA

```
COD_DISCI DESCRICAO                     CREDITOS   TB_CURSO_COD_CURSO
---------- --------------------------- ---------- ------------------
         1 REDES                                6                  1
         2 BANCO DE DADOS                       6                  3
         3 ALGORITMO                            4                  2
         4 SISTEMAS OPERACIONAIS                4                  3
```

#### TB_CURSO

```
 COD_CURSO DESCRICAO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------- --------------
         1 REDES         
         2 ENGENHARIA    
         3 SISTEMAS
```

#### Função para ser criada

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION <nome do função>
(parâmetros – variável e tipo de dado)
RETURN <tipo de dado retornado>
BEGIN
<implementação da função>
RETURN <variável>
END;;
```

Comment: Eu entendi errado ou a relação curso-disciplina está 1-n? Não deveria ser n-n?

Comment: Relacionamento é TB_DISCIPLINA (1,n)  curso_disciplina TB_Curso (1,1). Eu acho que assim fica mais claro.

Comment: Concordo com o Ronaldo.

Comment: Seu modelo está meio estranho e por isso estão estranhando sua modelagem. Pelo exemplo que você listou cada curso tem uma única disciplina, não é estranho?

Comment: Estava revendo meu modelo e acredito que esteja correto, por que existe a tabela matricula, onde armazena o COD_ALUNO e também o COD_DISCIPLINA. Vou colocar o print dessa tabela.

Comment: @MarcianoLazari Isso não muda o fato de o curso estar ligado a uma única disciplina...é essa a ideia mesmo?

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves Não, um curso pode esta ligado a várias disciplinas.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves Acredito que agora tenha ficado correta, alterei a estrutura das tabelas, acredito que estavam erradas mesmo! veja agora!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplo funcional.
Tentei colocar no http://sqlfiddle.com, porém como tem função não consegui.

#### Tabelas

```
create table TB_DISCIPLINA (
  COD_DISCI number(10),
  DESCRICAO varchar2(255),
  CREDITOS number(10),
  TB_CURSO_COD_CURSO number(10)
);

create table TB_CURSO (
  COD_CURSO number(10),
  DESCRICAO varchar2(255)
);
```

#### Registros

```
insert into TB_DISCIPLINA values (1, 'REDES', 6, 1);
insert into TB_DISCIPLINA values (2, 'BANCO DE DADOS', 6, 3);
insert into TB_DISCIPLINA values (3, 'ALGORITMO', 4, 2);
insert into TB_DISCIPLINA values (4, 'SISTEMAS OPERACIONAIS', 4, 3);

insert into TB_CURSO values (1, 'REDES');
insert into TB_CURSO values (2, 'ENGENHARIA');
insert into TB_CURSO values (3, 'SISTEMAS');
```

#### Função

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION QTDE_CREDITOS_CURSO (curso integer)
return integer 
as
  creditos integer;
begin
  select sum(CREDITOS) into creditos from TB_DISCIPLINA where TB_CURSO_COD_CURSO = curso;
  return creditos;
end;
/
```

#### Exemplo de Utilização

```
select 
  Descricao as Curso,
  QTDE_CREDITOS_CURSO(cod_curso) as Creditos
from 
  TB_CURSO
where cod_curso = 2;
```

Comment: Estou muito Grato! Resolvido!